# python modules accessing files in "local" directory

Tags: python

I have simple question.
I have a python module "dev1.py" that needs a file "dev1_blob"

If I have everything in one directory.
my_app loads the dev1 like

```
from dev1 import func1
```

it works fine.
I want to move dev1.py to a directory "./dev_files" with **init**.py in it.I can load the dev1.py as

```
from dev_files.dev1 import func1
```

However when func1 runs to access the "device_blob"  -- it barfs as:

```
  resource not found ..
```

This is so basic that I believe I am missing something.
I can't figure out why great minds of python want everything to refer to `__file__` (cwd) and force me to modify dev1.py based on where it's being run from. i.e. in dev1.py refer to the file as: `'dev_files/device_blob'`

I can make it work this way, but it's purely absurd way of writing code.
Is there a simple way to access a file next to the module files or  in the tree below?

Comment: what is `device_blob`?

Comment: Just a plain file

Answer (score 1):

Relative pathing is one of Python's larger flaws.

For this use case, you might be able to call `open('../dev_files/device_blob')` to go back a dir first.

My general solution is to have a "project.py" file containing an absolute path to the project directory. Then I call `open(os.path.join(PROJECT_DIR, 'dev_files', 'device_blob'))`.

Comment: this  doesn't solve the general problem -- it's a bit more "visible" but at the expense of having to maintain 2 items instead of one now!   Maybe  there is no clean solution -- when it's so fundamentally broken. Though I can't see why it hasn't been fixed in the language -- it doesn't seem to be that difficult a problem to fix.

Comment: what're the two items to maintain? the "project.py" file, and something else?

Comment: One way is to do what I had written earlier - i.e. hard code the "relative path" in the code (in the file that needs it, add the hard relation)- Your suggestion is to leave that as is, and then hard code another piece of information .. I see that as a second item to maintain. But thanks for the suggestion and clarification that this is a python flaw.